# How do I consume a web service secured by OAuth?

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm very new to WSO2 esb and I'm still evaluating it. I'm trying to consume a web service secured by OAuth. In my sequence I created a mediator OAuth like this snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="test-consume-oauth_v1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <in>
        <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="test-consume-oauth_v1 Body_received" scope="default" type="STRING" />

        <oauthService xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  password="xxx"
            remoteServiceUrl="https://myserver.com/token" username="xxx"/>
        <call>
            <endpoint key="test_OAUTH_v1"/>
        </call>

        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var srvResponse = mc.getPayloadJSON();
            mc.setProperty('srvResponse', srvResponse);]]></script>
        <log>
             <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="test-consume-oauth_v1 response "/>
        </log>
        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();

            mc.setPayloadJSON(mc.getProperty('srvResponse'));   

        ]]></script>

        <respond  />
    </in>
    <out>
        <send />
        <drop />
    </out>
</sequence>
```

But it still display this error:

```
MessageID: urn:uuid:ba554008-3b7c-4a96-875b-d04cc8fa179b, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Not a valid OAuth Request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

when I try using cURL command line it works no problem:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer 3ef47ff9ae9f0600aa279a0f77ddfdf" "https://myserver.com/ws-test" -k
```

To sum up how I ca do the samething in Wso2 esb like the cURL command line ?

Best regards

Comment: Enable wirelogs and check whether the request goes from ESB is correct

Comment: Can you post the request made to esb (body,http headers) to the question ? according to the error it says not a valid oauth request, make sure you send oauth token header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxx'

Answer (score 0):

I use the mediator header like that

```
<header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="3ef47ff9ae9f0600aa27efd6565" />

<call>
       <endpoint key="test_OAUTH_v1"/>
</call>
 ....
```

Thats works good. But the problem is that the token lifetime is short, so I have to store the current token and if it's not valid I have to ask for a new valid token. I think that wso2esb do this process but I don't know how I can process.

Would you have any propositions ?

Answer (score 0):

oauth mediator is used to secure an unsecured backend using oauth. In your case your backend is already secured by oauth and you need to invoke that backned through esb by providing the oauth token. Where you need to dynamically generate the oauth token using password grant type and use it to call the backend. So you can follow below steps in your sequence to achieve this

1. Create the payload for token endpoint using payload factory mediator.
   payload to the token endpoint - "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=xxx"

```html
 <property name="grant_type" value="password" scope="default" type="STRING"/> 
    <property name="username" value="admin" scope="default" type="STRING"/>/> 
    <property name="password" value="xxxx" scope="default" type="STRING"/>/> 
                
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format> 
                        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
                            <soapenv:Body> 
                                <root> 
                                    <grant_type>$1</grant_type> 
                                    <username>$2</username> 
                                    <country>$3</country>                                
                                </root> 
                            </soapenv:Body> 
                        </soapenv:Envelope> 
                    </format> 
                    <args> 
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:grant_type"/> 
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:username"/> 
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:password"/> 
                   </args> 
    </payloadFactory>            
    <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/> 
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

2. Call the token endpoint using call mediator and extract the token from  response and add to authorization header

a.

```html
<call> 
       <endpoint key="TokenEndpoint"/> 
 </call>
```

b. 
Extract the token from response

c. 
set the token to authorization header using header mediator

3.Call the actual backend

Comment: Tanks Jenanthan I tried your code but it doesn't work